# Game of Life with file read for world generation. How to get file to display world properly?

Tags: python, list, function, file, variables

Like the title says, I've being working on a variant of Conway's Game of Life in python that can read a "world" and generate some elements from a file and generate the starting world from that. However, in my code, the world is being displayed as

```
([['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['*', '*', ' '], ['*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']], 10, 6)
```

When I am trying to get it to look like this as it is from the imported file.

```
*     
** 
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

I have no clue on how to get this program to display it properly as I have tried to edit around the list variables, but nothing I am doing is actually doing anything, as it either displays it wrong or just gives me an error. Can anyone here point me in the right direction?

Thank you for the help, and please let me know if there's any additional info I should provide

```
def main():
    world = []
    while True:
        try:
            filename = input("Name of input file: ")
            for aLine in open(filename,"r"):
                world.append(list(aLine[:-1]))
            if world:
                maxRows = len(world)
                maxColumns = len(world[0])
                return world, maxRows, maxColumns
            print("The file %s" %(filename), "is empty.")
        except IOError:
            print("Problem reading from file %s" %(filename))

print(main())
```

Comment: What is this input supposed to mean?
What do you expect it to look like when displayed?

Comment: Like the triangle display

Comment: @Samwise has the correct answer below.

It also seems you need to update your code like so,
```maxColumns = max([len(i) for i in world[0]])```

Comment: Where would I put? Sorry if I sound dull but, its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join` and/or the `sep` parameter to `print()`:

```
>>> world, rows, columns = ([['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['*', '*', ' '], ['*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']], 10, 6)
>>> print(*(''.join(row) for row in world), sep='\n')
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
*********
>>> print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in world))
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
*********
>>> for row in world:
...     print(*row, sep='')
...
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
*********
```

Comment: if world:
                maxRows = len(world)
                maxColumns = len(world[0])
                print(*(''.join(row) for row in world), sep='\n')
                return world, maxRows, maxColumns
            print("The file %s" %(filename), "is empty.")
        except IOError:
            print("Problem reading from file %s" %(filename))   Like this? Because I get both now, instead of the array i had wanted.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask there -- but if `world` has the value that you posted in your original question, then the code above should print it the way you want.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now.  Don't print inside your function, and don't just print what `main()` returns.  Do `world, rows, cols = main()` and then the code to print `world` with the correct formatting.

Comment: Im inserting the code in between (maxColumns = len(world[0]) and (return world, maxRows, maxColumns, but the resulting display is that of the triangle and the initial long line. Where do I place it so that it doesn't display the wrong one?

Comment: tl;dr: Don't print stuff that you don't want to print.  :)

Comment: Wait, so would I make another function to print it out or am I missing something?

Comment: You could and probably should do that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this.

```
def main():
    # get the file to read
    filename = input("Name of input file: ")

    # open, read, and close the file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        world = [list(line[:-1]) for line in f]
    
    # get derived information
    rows = len(world)
    columns = max([len(i) for i in world])
    world_printable = '\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in world])

    return world, rows, columns, world_printable
    

world, rows, columns, world_printable = main()
print(world_printable)
```

If you ONLY want to print the file, you could just do,

```
def main():
    # get the file to read
    filename = input("Name of input file: ")

    # open, read, and close the file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
             print(line.strip())

main()
```

Comment: when I use print(main()), it still prints the line

Comment: updated it for you, but it's essentially rewritten. Where did you see this exercise?

Comment: This is an incredibly brutal project for my 11th grade comp sci class. Thanks for your help!

Comment: bonus points for a one liner: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/python/game-life-one-line/